Is it possible to model two-phase flow in a model with dynamic pipe?
Does anyone have an example of a two-phase flow model with dynamic pipe?
I'm trying to implement the “two phase flow” example but I think it only extends the properties of water. I'm a new user of open modelica so I don't think I understand how it works.

I suggest you take a look at the WaterSteam.HeatExchangers.DynamicTwoPhaseFlowPipe from the ThermoSysPro library. The connectors remain "single-phase" and treat the pressure, mass flowrate and specific enthalpy of the mixture. But that's a good starting point!
I believe it is included in OpenModelica, otherwise you can retrieve it on Github.

Thank you for your reply,
I don't have access to this library, don't you think I can use the “Fixed composition value” option in dynamic pipe to impose a fixed steam value on the input source?

You mean in Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe? I don't see this option. Anyway, you would need two balance equations for mass, heat and momentum. I don't know if having two connectors (one for liquid and one for vapour) would be silly...

Yes, in the dynamic driving option, you can choose to define composition X and substance C. I don't know how to use this option, but as you say, I can enter two sources, one for steam (ideal steam) and the other for liquid water (standard water). By doing this, the system doesn't converge. Pipes support only one definition medium

Those would be for advection or multi-species (single phase) flow. It all depends on the level of modelling you want: a 6 equations model is the most detailed, whereas a 3+1 (for composition) is a more modest one.
